# Setting a predefined dropdown list to tk Entry widget box

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import os
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sys
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pickle
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandastable

os.chdir('C:/Users/paulc/Documents/Medium Football')

# load the excel file
wb = load_workbook('BettingLog.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active


window=Tk()
window.title("Betting Log")
window.geometry("800x550")
main_lst=[]
bookmakers_list = ['Betfair Sportsbook','Betfair Exchange','BetVictor','SkyBet','Unibet']
bookie_variable = StringVar(window)
bookie_variable.set(bookmakers_list[0]) #default value

# 3 labels, 4 buttons,3 entry fields
label1=Label(window,text="Selection:",padx=20,pady=10)
label2=Label(window,text="Stake: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label3=Label(window,text="Odds: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label4=Label(window,text="TrueOdds: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label5=Label(window,text="Bookmaker: ",padx=20,pady=10)
label6=Label(window,text="Result: ",padx=20,pady=10)




Selection=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)
Stake=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)
Odds=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)
TrueOdds=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)
bookie_variable=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)
Result=Entry(window,width=30,borderwidth=3)



def Add():
   new_line = sheet.max_row + 1
   sheet.cell(column=1, row=new_line, value=Selection.get())
   sheet.cell(column=2, row=new_line, value=Stake.get())
   sheet.cell(column=3, row=new_line, value=Odds.get())
   sheet.cell(column=4, row=new_line, value=TrueOdds.get())
   sheet.cell(column=5, row=new_line, value=bookie_variable.get())
   sheet.cell(column=6, row=new_line, value=Result.get())
   messagebox.showinfo("Information","The data has been added successfully")
   wb.save(filename="Received Proposals.xlsx")
def Save():
      wb.save('BettingLog.xlsx')
      messagebox.showinfo("Information saved succesfully","Saved!")

def Clear():
   Selection.delete(0,END)
   Stake.delete(0,END)
   Odds.delete(0,END)
   TrueOdds.delete(0, END)
   bookie_variable.delete(0, END)
   Result.delete(0, END)

save=Button(window,text="Save",padx=20,pady=10,command=Save)
add=Button(window,text="Add",padx=20,pady=10,command=Add)
clear=Button(window,text="Clear",padx=18,pady=10,command=Clear)
Exit=Button(window,text="Exit",padx=20,pady=10,command=window.quit)

label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)
label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
label4.grid(row=3,column=0)
label5.grid(row=4,column=0)
label6.grid(row=5,column=0)


Selection.grid(row=0,column=1)
Stake.grid(row=1,column=1)
Odds.grid(row=2,column=1)
TrueOdds.grid(row=3,column=1)
bookie_variable.grid(row=4,column=1)
Result.grid(row=5,column=1)



add.grid(row=0,column=12,columnspan=2)
save.grid(row=0,column=15,columnspan=2)
clear.grid(row=0,column=18,columnspan=2)
Exit.grid(row=0,column=21,columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

The above code creates a gui with multiple entry boxes where it appends what is typed to the excel file,

how would i set predefined lists as an entry drop down for the bookmaker entry box.

say the list is bookies = ['Betfair','Skybet']

the desired functionality would be a sort of drop down menu for that entry box that only allows me to select either of those values

any ideaS?

Comment: Is this your understanding of providing a minimal example?

Comment: `tk.Entry` can't use `drop down` list. You have to use different widget. [tk.OptionMenu](https://web.archive.org/web/20200704224617/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`tk.Entry` can't use `drop down` list. You have to use different widget. [tk.OptionMenu](https://web.archive.org/web/20200704224617/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def on_select(selected):   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    print('[on_select]:', selected)
    print('[on_select]:', variable.get())
    print('---')

def on_press():
    print('[on_press]:', variable.get())
    print('---')
    
# --- main ---

data = ['Betfair Sportsbook','Betfair Exchange','BetVictor','SkyBet','Unibet']

root = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(data[0]) # default value

dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *data, command=on_select)
dropdown.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_press)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)